# How to manage SCSS when a project has launched

Tags: css, version-control, sass

I was wondering how you would go about managing `.SCSS` files when a project has launched. For example I manage a number of websites & use the power of `SCSS` while building them.

However once a project has launched if I'm required to make a small edit currently I just ftp to the minified `.css` file and tag the extra few lines to the bottom... Bad I know!

Then when it comes to a larger change to an existing project the `.scss` files are rendered unless as the `.css` is ahead of the `.scss` therefore re-compiling the `.scss` will overwrite smaller chnages that have taken place.

The only way I could think to go about this would be to create an `_updates.scss` file and tagging all the small updates into this file. However this will take much longer than the current ftp'd changes.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Why don't you always edit the scss files when a change is needed, and then reupload the outputted css to the ftp every time?

Comment: Currently because of time if we need to make a minor change such as font-size you can easily edit that in a few seconds. Where as you would need to download the scss/css files setup in a scss compiler make the changes and compile/ re-upload.

Also if the css edit isn't as simple but still small you may need to download an entire website set it up locally test your changes compile and re-upload an entire site.

Comment: Anything I have on the web, I have a backup set up locally. It only takes a few seconds to update the local sass file and upload the compiled CSS file. It sounds to me like you have no backup of your site and that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest still using Sass, it seems a waste not to after you've used it this far too for building the majority of the styling. It sounds like less of a Sass vs CSS issue (once on live) but more of a poor workflow.

If it seems slow editing once it's on live, consider an improved workflow - Use Git for version control (or similar), and possibly setup deployments, along with Grunt/Gulp to make Sass watches and recompiling a little easier to once it's all setup (sometimes it's a good idea to extend the functionality of these task runners to lint and minify code). Then you can stay up to date (using Git), make required changes and then you can deploy the compiled stylesheets. I use this simple workflow for a lot of projects, big and small and it's very efficient. Keeping an efficient level of maintainability for codebases is essential i think, and the first place you can improve this is your workflow. (see above)

Comment: Yes, this. Making edits at the end (or anywhere except the beginning of the pipeline) is just opening a big bag of hurt. If the workflow takes too long, then iron out the inefficiencies in the pipeline.